# How to extract a specific string from a key,value pair data in Big Query using regexp_extract?

Tags: regex, bigdata, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract the value for a particular key 'xyz' and tried the below regex expression to accomplish it. Is this an effective method to deal with key value pairs? Can someone suggest me if there is any other solution which is more effective. Thank you.

```
**

 - Input & SQL :-



**

 SELECT FIRST( SPLIT( regexp_extract(kvp,r'SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator=(.*)&'), '&' ) ) AS SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator,
       regexp_extract(kvp,r'campaignName=(.*)$') AS campaign,
       regexp_extract(LOWER(kvp),r'resultcode=(.*)&') AS resultcode,       
  FROM ( SELECT 'SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator=True&templateVersionId=5&vmtaText=mail2&sequenceId=300&resultCode=DoNotMailBounceList&campaignName=classicimport' AS kvp )

Output :-

    SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator campaign        resultcode   
    True                                classicimport   donotmailbouncelist
```

Comments :-

In the above SQL I am using FIRST(SPLIT()) to extract the sub-string from the input which I think that it's not effective and can be implemented just by using regular expression.Please kindly share your insights if there is any other possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use slightly different regular expressions to avoid SPLIT and FIRST costs, as well as encoding special knowledge about parameter positions in URL:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(kvp,r'SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator=([^&]*)') AS SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator,
       regexp_extract(kvp,r'campaignName=([^&]*)') AS campaign,
       regexp_extract(LOWER(kvp),r'resultcode=([^&]*)') AS resultcode,       
  FROM ( SELECT 'SuppressFlexCacheHydrationIndicator=True&templateVersionId=5&vmtaText=mail2&sequenceId=300&resultCode=DoNotMailBounceList&campaignName=classicimport' AS kvp )
```

Comment: Thanks Mohsa. It works fine. Can you explain me the usage of [^&]*. By looking at the result I understand that we are looking for the first ampersand that follows the key. Is this right interpretation?

Comment: The [^&] means any character except &, so the regular expression match will stop when it sees & in the input.

Comment: Thank you. Just wondering if you know/have any good documentation(or suggestions) that has more details about regex in BQ. I have checked the native BQ documentation for regex but its very limited.